# Can ArcGIS Desktop create LAS (or lasd) files from ASCII data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, lidar, las, xyz

I have many ASCII files containing LiDAR xyz values. In order to create an ArcGIS LASD file, I need to convert these ASCII files into las files. I can do this with FME or LAStools, but I can't see a way in ArcGIS.

Does anyone know if this is possible in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.x?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there's an option to convert any file format to LAS within ArcGIS, out of the box.

You can support this idea (there are also additional suggestions on the page): https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/4809

Answer (score 2):

Workaround for creating a stripped down LAS file:

1. Create XYZ fields on point file.
2. Populate X field via update geometry. Repeat for Y and Z.
3. Create ascii file (generate format). Requires *3D Analyst/Feature Class Z to ASCII*.
4. Import XYZ fields to LAS.

Alternatively, *Data Management Tools/Features/Add XY Coordinates* will create and populate XYZ fields to singularly process steps A and B.

Comment: Thank you for your work around. I think I will keep using FME. I really wanted to keep my workflow in ArcGIS so that all my colleagues could use the same method, but this looks unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think ArcGIS should be your software of choice for **producing** proper LAS files because Esri added support for LiDAR very late and was [not a contributing partner of the LAS community](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LIDAR_Format_Letter).

Although ArcGIS can now consume LAS files and generate a number of derivatives, I would advise you to stick with LiDAR softwares that are specialized in producing **specification-compliant** LAS or LAZ files. There are many ways one can get this wrong and generate less-than-optimal LAS files.

If you insist on doing it within ArcGIS then you could have a look at our [LAStools toolbox for ArcGIS](https://rapidlasso.com/2013/07/02/arcgis-lastools-toolbox-for-lidar-processing/)  and the free and open source '[txt2las](http://lastools.org/download/txt2las_README.txt)' tool.

**Disclaimer**: I am the developer of LAStools.

Comment: Only the third paragraph here really comes close to answering the question, the rest seems to be personal opinion/bias (as per your last line).  As you appear to be promoting your own product here, please [edit] your answer to include disclosure of your affiliation with the product (see [help/behavior]), and I'd suggest removing the opinion and focus on answering the question